# Connect the access db(ms-access) on the server with tcp

Tags: iphone, ms-access, tcp

i am doing an iphone app,and i have some trouble,so can anybody teaches me ?

how can i connect the access DB(ms-access) on server with tcp?

thanks a lot

Comment: I think you have no business using a Jet/ACE data store if you don't even know enough about the database engine to realize that there can't possibly be any access to it via TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely not possible, you should use a proper SQL server and a webservice/REST service to access the data.